# fit negative binomial in mediation path models with FIML and bootstrap in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I've been analyzing longitudinal data for mediation path models in R. But my outcome is highly positively skewed, so regular regression does not work (too skewed to fit Poisson).

lavaan does not support negative binomial (I checked with the lavaan group where the developer of lavaan answers questions).

I already tried dichotomizing the outcome and using lavaan. But lavaan can't use FIML for binary options (only pairwise), so I lose 1/3 of participants in that way, and I don't like losing information from dichotomizing anyway.

I want to continue to use bootstrap instead of manually checking a, b, c, and c'.

My collaborator and I are trying to avoid multiple imputation.

I don't have MPlus, and I want to continue to use R.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my model using lavaan:

```
p16a18c24 <- ' 
# direct effect
myOutcome ~ c*myPredictor
# mediator
myMediator1 ~ a1*myPredictor
myOutcome ~ b1*myMediator1
myMediator2 ~ a2*myPredictor
myOutcome ~ b2*myMediator2
myMediator3 ~ a3*myPredictor
myOutcome ~ b3*myMediator3
# variances: any variable that was listed as DV
myOutcome ~~ myOutcome 
myMediator1 ~~ myMediator1
myMediator2 ~~ myMediator2
myMediator3 ~~ myMediator3
# covariances: mediators who are (positively) correlated with each other 
myMediator1 ~~ myMediator2
myMediator2 ~~ myMediator3
myMediator3 ~~ myMediator1
# intercepts: *1, only for DVs 
myOutcome ~ 1 
myMediator1 ~ 1
myMediator2 ~ 1
myMediator3 ~ 1
# indirect effects (a*b)
ab1 := a1*b1
ab2 := a2*b2
ab3 := a3*b3
# total effect
total := c + (a1*b1) + (a2*b2) + (a3*b3)
'
fit.p16a18c24 <- sem(p16a18c24,data=m,missing="fiml",se="bootstrap")
summary(fit.p16a18c24,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE,rsquare=TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance,

GN